# The regular expression in the FILTER option of gcovr

Tags: regex, gcov, gcovr

I use `gcovr` to read coverage information for program foo.c. The syntax is

```
gcovr -r . -b --filter=FILE_PATTERN
```

where the '-r .' part indicates the current directory as the search root, '-b' is for branch coverage, and the FILE_PATTERN part  is to keep only the data files that match this regular expression, according to gcovr's user guide http://gcovr.com/guide.html.

So I use this following command line

```
gcovr -r . -b --filter='foo\\.c'
```

But this command finds no information regarding foo.c retrieved. It seems I use a wrong regular expression. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your file's name is literally:  foo\.c
That regex won't match.

In regex, the double backslash creates a literal backslash.
You may be confusing regex escape sequences and C/C++ string escape sequences.

If your file's name is literally:  foo.c
Use this regex pattern:  foo\.c

Comment: I have used `--exclude='.*Test.*'` to exclude any file with "Test" in the name, yet many files such as `TestIO.cpp` are still being reported - any suggestions?

Comment: @DavidDoria Are you still affected by that problem? If you could make a small example project to reproduce this using an up-to-date gcovr, I would love to get a bug report on the gcovr project :)

Comment: @amon Sorry, I haven't looked at this in a long, long time and don't have the bandwidth to do so at the moment.